# Does applying standard normalisation lead to normal distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, mean, standardization

Does applying standard normalisation to data variables mean changing the distribution of data variables to normal distribution having mean=0 and variance=1?

Answer (score 4):

Take any sample $(x_i)$, subtract the empirical mean $m$ and divide by the empirical standard deviation $s$ to obtain $(\widetilde{x}_i)$:

$$ \widetilde{x}_i := \frac{x_i-m}{s}. $$

Then $(\widetilde{x}_i)$ will have mean 1 and standard deviation 1 (so its variance will also be 1).

However, it will not be normally distributed. The normal distribution is the familiar "bell shape", and the *standard* normal has the "bell" of a particular width (the variance) and at a particular place (the mean). Not every distribution with the same center and the same width automatically has the correct "bell" shape. Standardization shifts and scales a distribution; it does not change its shape.

For instance, here is a histogram of Poisson distributed variables with parameter $\lambda=\ln 2$, and its standardization as per above. The standardized variables have mean 0 and variance 1, but they are certainly not normally distributed. Note how the bars of the histograms have different width; this is a consequence of the scaling.

[image: standardization]

R code:

```
set.seed(1)
xx <- rpois(1e4,log(2))
xx_tilde <- (xx-mean(xx))/sd(xx)
opar <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))
    hist(xx,breaks=seq(-.5,max(xx)+.5),col="gray",xlim=c(-2,7))
    hist(xx_tilde,col="gray",xlim=c(-2,7),
        breaks=seq(min(xx_tilde)-sd(xx)/2,max(xx_tilde)+sd(xx),by=mean(diff(unique(xx_tilde)))))
par(opar)
```

---

There is no "normalization" of data. There is no way you can take a given sample $x$ and change it in a meaningful way to something that is normally distributed *in general*. If your original data are lognormal, you can take logarithms and end up with normally distributed data. (If you want, you can then standardize it as above to end up with a *standard* normal distribution.) But if you start off with a general distribution, the best you can do is generate normally distributed random numbers that are in some way "inspired" by $x$. For an illustration, look at different [beta distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). These are confined to a finite interval (the normal distribution lives on the entire real line), they can be symmetric or asymmetric, they can be uni- or bimodal.