# Does a uniform random distribution become a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

I have $N$ numbers from uniform random distribution. Now I have done a transformation on these $N$ numbers as: each $x$ is converted to $\frac{(x-\mu_N)}{\sigma_N}$. Where $\mu_N$ is the mean of $N$ numbers and $\sigma_N$ is the standard deviation of those $N$ numbers. Does the converted distribution follow a normal distribution?

Comment: Your transformation amounts to changing the units in which you express the values, just like changing from degrees F to degrees C.  We should all hope that such an arbitrary choice would *not* change the distribution!

Answer (score 6):

Try it:

```r
> X <- runif(500000)
> hist(X, 20)
> hist((X-mean(X))/sd(X), 20)
```

[image: The histograms were created using the above code. The first one is uniform, and the second one is uniformish, with slightly smaller bars on bounds.]

The plot above is slightly misleading, as there is a plotting artifact that makes it look as if it was not exactly uniform, but it is. To convince yourself, draw a plot for uniform distribution with bounds equal to the lowest and highest value from the sample above, the plot would look the same. Since R has a problem with drawing histograms for data that does not have "round" bounds, I've drawn the probability distribution function of this distribution.

```r
> hist(runif(500000, min((X-mean(X))/sd(X)), max((X-mean(X))/sd(X))), 20, freq=F)
> curve(dunif(x, min((X-mean(X))/sd(X)), max((X-mean(X))/sd(X))), min((X-mean(X))/sd(X)), max((X-mean(X))/sd(X)), col="red", add=T, lw=3)
```

[image: Plot created using the code above. Uniformish-looking histogram with first and last bars slightly lover. Over it, plotted uniform PDF.]

It's flat and it's exactly the same distribution you got by scaling the data. What the scaling did is it shifted each of the values by mean and multiplied it by the standard deviation. If you transform a random variable in such a way, it will change the mean, standard deviation, and bounds of the distribution, but not the shape of the distribution. It creates a [location-scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family) variant of uniform distribution. If $f(x)$ is the probability distribution function of uniform distribution, then after subtracting mean $a$ and dividing by standard deviation $b$, you get

$$
g(x) = \tfrac{1}{b} f\big(\tfrac{x-a}{b}\big)
$$

so it cannot have a different shape than $f$. It's just wider and shorter, so its area under the curve remains equal to $1$, as required by a probability distribution.

The result is not surprising, as subtracting the mean and dividing by standard deviation [doesn't transform any distribution to Gaussian](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360323/does-applying-standard-normalisation-lead-to-normal-distribution).

Comment: we can see it as an approximate bell? greater than 1.5 and less than -1.5 values have less frequency?

Comment: @AJ no it's not. It's a plotting artifact. This transformation does nothing that could transform the distribution to Gaussian. The distribution keeps the same shape, just its mean and standard deviation (and bounds) change.

Comment: @Tim presumably you can change the binning bounds so that there is no so called "plotting artifact"? Why didn't you do that?

Comment: @justhalf I tried different numbers of bins with not much luck. I don't feel like debugging R quirks. Also, I feel like it makes a nice educatory example of not taking plots at face value.

Comment: There's no `R` bug here, but "quirk" is a good characterization.  When you set the breakpoints manually to run from the minimum to the maximum of the data, you won't see such partial-height bars in the histogram.

Comment: @whuber well yes, if you provide the breakpoints to it yourself...

Comment: When examining data that might have a sharp cutoff at either end, I try to make that effort because I want to communicate the results accurately. It doesn't take any more effort, either.  This solution is a little shorter than yours: `y = scale(runif(5e5)); hist(y, seq(min(y), max(y), length.out = 20), freq = F)`

Comment: `plot(density(X)); plot(density((X-mean(X))/sd(X)))` might illustrate the point (there is stll a smaller tail effect, but it is the same with the original data and the scaled relocated data)

Comment: @Tim but a and b are both dependent on max and min values of the uniform distribution right?? also, 1 std deviation beyond the mean will have very less data points right? similarly for 2std beyond mean we have even fewer points right?

Comment: @AJ min and max will depend on data, sure, so what? What do you mean by 1sd beyond mean will have less data, less than what? The distribution is uniform so it has equal probability density for any point.

Comment: @Tim Since min and max depend on data why are they being treated as constants? They should be parameters in terms of datapoints know? is there any concrete proof for this?

Comment: @AJ Proof for what? The distribution remains uniform, estimating its parameters is a different story.

Comment: Proof of why the distribution remains same? as in a and b are not constants right? they are dependent on the data right?

Comment: @AJ it doesn't remain the same, it remains uniform. There is no reason why it would change, why would you expect that?

Answer (score 0):

In order for your sample to follow a normal distribution, you may want to feed it to a normal distribution's **quantile function**, which is:
$\mu+\sigma\sqrt2 erf^{-1}(2x-1)$ where $erf^{-1}$ is the inverse error function. Or you could simply feed you sample into the function `qnorm()` in R:

```r
N <- 1000
sample <- runif(1000)
normal <- qnorm(sample, mean=10, sd=4)
hist(normal)
```

In both cases, you choose the mean ($\mu$) and standard distribution ($\sigma$) yourself.
[image]

Comment: This advice without any comment on why and when this would be useful is like answering “can I hang myself on toilet paper?” with “no, you need decent rope”.

Comment: The motivation of the topic starter is not clear either. But it will let him/her know which function will transform the input into the normal sample. Your comment is like a comment "your advice is garbage, because you did explain how to use the rope"  to an answer "no, you need decent rope".